# Knowing when to store what in $sp

Tags: assembly, mips

When translating code from C to MIPS, I've been struggling to understand when we store registers such as a0-a3 and s0-s7 in $sp.

I understand that we save the return address $ra when we have function calls.

I also understand that we save arguments when they are going to change later on in the code such as when doing factorial int factorial(n-1)

But other than these cases, how do I know when something should be stored in $sp.

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of text on this but perhaps yet one more explanation will help.

You need to understand

- when to use what register

  - this is motivated by liveness analysis of variables in a function.
- how to follow the rules for that given register, which includes

  - what and when to save and same for restore.

---

All the call-preserved registers, also known with the (somewhat poorer) term callee-saves, must obey the rule that their original value shall be returned to the caller, period (full-stop).  If you're writing a function and it does not use some call-preserved registers, then there is nothing to do, we simply assume that all are following the rules, so no need to save & restore them if your function is not using them.

However, if you want to use one in a function you're writing, you must both save in prologue & restore in epilogue any registers of this set whose values you alter.  (You don't have to worry about any other functions that you call and what call-preserved registers they use — just preserve the ones that this function actually modifies.)

Call-preserved registers have the advantage that the values held in them survive a function call.  This advantage comes with some overhead, namely to save these registers in prologue and restore them in epilogue — there's no magic hardware here for these registers, these rules are how these register are preserved by a call.

Using these registers is a performance advantage when the function you're writing has variables that are heavily used, e.g. used multiple times, and there's function calling in between the various usages.  A good example, is a function that has a loop, that within the loop, has a function call.  For the live variables of the loop, call-preserved registers are efficient storage.  A loop doing say, `printf`, will need at least the loop control variable to survive the call to `printf`.

The usage pattern for call-preserved registers then is: the presumption that, for each call-preserved register, some caller further up the call chain (and thus, which happened further back in time than your function's invocation), is holding a value therein.  So, your job in writing a new function is to preserve the illusion to the callers that these registers don't change in value, by saving whatever is there upon the start of your new function and restoring it upon return (assuming you will want to use one of these registers) — saving/restoring a value you don't know for the benefit of some caller (who called your new function) that you don't know.

On MIPS the call-preserved registers are the `$s0`-`$s7`.

I'll also add that the stack pointer itself must be restored to its original value upon return, but this is usually done by merely deallocating any and all allocated stack space rather than save & restore involving memory storage.

---

The other registers have a different usage pattern: they are saved & restored for your own benefit — for the benefit of the new function you're writing rather than for the benefit of any caller.

These are called scratch registers, also known as call-clobbered, and also by the very poor name caller-saves.  These registers should be presumed to be wiped out by a function call (unless you actually know the internal implementation details of function(s) being called, and also want to deviate from the calling convention).

So, any values held in these registers, if needed after a call, must be saved somewhere that they will survive the call, but again, only if needed within the function you're writing, and after some function call that uses the standard calling convention.

The caller-saves model name suggests say that we will empty these registers before a call and restore them after a call (if we know we may need them after), however, in practical usage they are rarely used exactly this way — instead the compiler or assembly programmer moves these values somewhere else and only restores them on demand of the function being writing and not necessarily back to the same register, either.

Because the concern here is to save & restore values your own new function uses, we need to introduce the notion of live variable analysis, which is a local analysis you can perform on the variables of your function.  Such analysis is automatically done by the compiler.

The scratch (call-clobbered) registers are never restored in epilogue for the benefit of the caller — there's no point; a standard calling convention caller won't expect them to come back with their original values.

This includes the argument registers, `$a0`-`$a3`, as well as the temp registers `$t0`-`$t9`.

And also includes the return address register `$ra`, which is a parameter to your function (the address to return to no matter who called your new function), which is hidden in C and other languages.  By convention, we restore the return address to the `$ra` register, but not for the benefit of the caller, rather so we can use it ourselves (via `jr $ra`) to return to the specific caller.  (Turns out hardware benefits from these patterns, in using a shadow return stack.)

---

One scenario is that, by the calling convention, your formal parameters are passed in registers, and these registers are in the call-clobbered aka scratch set.  If live variable analysis shows that the formal parameter variable is not live across a function call, you're golden, and just leave it in that register to use from there.

If, however, analysis of that variable shows that it is live across some function call, you must take steps to preserve your variable's value somehow, since it is in a call-clobbered variable.

(Note that this applies to the potential for being live across some call, even if that call is conditionally executed/conditionally skipped).

In addition to formal parameter variables, similar analysis must take place for local variables — and also temporaries not seen in C code.

There are then two basic choices to make with such a variable found by analysis to be live across a call: place it in stack local memory, or place it in a call-preserved register, as both these storage locations survive function calls.

- For parameters that are heavily used, using a call-preserved register makes sense.  Stack space is allocated for the prior value held in the call-preserved register, which is saved & restored in prologue & epilogue.  The register is then initialized by copying the initial value into the chosen call-preserved register, and used from there.
- For parameters that are not heavily used, using a stack memory location makes sense.  Stack space is allocated for variable, and it is stored there before the first function call is made, and restored from there on the demands of the code in the new function (e.g. after the function).  If the value is needed after a function call, there's no particular reason to restore to the same register it had before.

  For example, let's say you have a 2nd parameter, that is passed in `$a1`, need it to survive a function call, but after the function call, need it in `$a0` — well just load it directly into `$a0` from its stack local memory location.

```
    void f ( int i, int j /* in $a1 */ ) {
       // save $a1 to stack allocated memory here in prologue.
       g(i);   // this function call kills scratch registers, e.g. $a0 and $a1
       h(j);   // load $a0 with from the stack memory where j is
    }
```

Let's note here that `i` is not live across a call — it is defined upon entry (it is a parameter) and it is used in body of this function in making the first call, but not thereafter — therefore it is not live across any call.  It comes in in `$a0`, and needs to be there for the call of `g`, so there's nothing to do for `i`.

Similarly, `j` is defined upon entry, but by contrast, not only is `j` live across a call (to `g`, that it is not involved in), but it is in the wrong location for its next usage — so it should be saved to a stack memory location (usually this would be done in prologue, but any time before `g` works as that's where it get's wiped out).  Since it is needed to make the call to `h` (after the `g` call), it is to be sent to where it is needed, which here is `$a0` (i.e. load from stack memory directly to `$a0`).

An `$s` register would also work for ensuring `j`'s value survives the `g` function call; however, in this scenario that would be just slightly less efficient in terms of instructions: space for, say `$s0` register allocated in prologue and that registers saved there; copy `$a1` into `$s0`, then make the call to `g` and setup the call to `h` by copying `$s0` to `$a0` — two more instructions than with the save directly to memory approach.  However, in other scenarios, the `$s` register usage wins.

---

> I understand that we save the return address $ra when we have function calls.

Yes: the return address is a parameter to our function informing where to return.  A function call within the body will necessarily repurpose `$ra` for that called function to return to us.  But we still need to return to our caller, so there's two `$ra` values involved.  Ours goes to memory so we can repurpose `$ra` for the call we're going to make, i.e. `jal function` will set an new value to `$ra`.

> I also understand that we save arguments when they are going to change later on in the code such as when doing factorial int factorial(n-1)

We save arguments that our own function needs later.  Like `$ra`, we wipe out some of the argument registers in just in setting up a new function call, but even if we don't wipe out all the scratch registers the newly called function is allowed to use them so we must presume they've been wiped out upon its return to us.

> When translating code from C to MIPS, I've been struggling to understand when we store registers such as a0-a3 and s0-s7 in $sp.

We save `$a0`-`$a3` for our function's own benefit when the formal parameter variables are live across a call in our own function, so these variables defined before a call, but needed by our own function body after a call.  There's no point to restoring these registers in epilogue (unless caller & callee choose to use a non-standard calling convention).

We save & restore `$s0`-`$s7` for the benefit of callers, and so that we can then use those registers in our own function, should we choose to do so for their simpler usage model within the body of our function, at the expense of additional handling in prologue & epilogue.

---

Let's also add that as long as the system uses a dynamic call stack, then recursion adds no additional requirements over ordinary function calling — all the requirements and rules already exist for ordinary function calling, so recursion doesn't add any new rules.  (It may add opportunities for use of non-standard calling conventions though, just as if you know the internal details of the code of both caller and callee, since with (direct) recursion, caller and callee are one and the same.)

---

Other than that, we use local stack storage for local arrays.  Many homework assignments will use global storage for arrays, as global storage can be allocated with the (relatively simple) `.space` or `.word` directives, and global storage can be named with labels.  Local storage does not use labels the same way as global storage, so allocating an array on the stack requires computing/remembering where the array is relative to the new stack pointer.

Comment: I got the main idea of what it is you're trying to tell me but I am a beginner to this course and could benefit from understanding the exercises i'm facing issues with such as writing this code in MIPS:

int count(int n)
{
   for(i=0; i!=n; i++)
     if(a[i]==x
    {
      loc[j]=i;
       j=j+1;
    }
  return loc
}

Comment: There's no function calling in that so, use only the $t registers and $v, no need then to save $ra or any $s registers.  However, there must be some typos as that C code won't compile.