# Why is my argument register not giving the right value in my MIPS assembly code

Tags: mips, mips32, mars-simulator

so ive written this MIPS code and im using MARS simulator 4.5. im supposed to list all permutations of 0,1,2,3 in this example in lexicographical order so the last (24th) permutation would be 3,2,1,0 and the problem is, that for one, when I jump to permnext function and try to copy $a0 contents into $t0 it just gives me a bogus number/ address that leads to somewhere in the .data section where I can see none of the numbers 0,1,2,3. I don't understand why that is. also I get an error when running the code, which is that the pc (program counter) is 0x0000... which it shouldn't be. thanks in advance

```
    #+ BITTE NICHT MODIFIZIEREN: Vorgabeabschnitt
    #+ ------------------------------------------

.data
str_Par: .asciiz "("
str_ColonTab: .asciiz "):\t"
str_Start: .asciiz "Das Programm ruft die Funktion permnext auf und zeigt Iterationsnummer und die neu gebildete Permutation an.\n"
str_Abbruch: .asciiz "Ausfuehrung abgebrochen (maximale Iterationsnummer erreicht).\n"
str_Spaces: .asciiz "  "
str_Break: .asciiz "\n"

.text

.eqv SYS_PUTSTR 4       #const define syscall ($v0)
.eqv SYS_RD_INT 5
.eqv SYS_PUTCHAR 11
.eqv SYS_PUTINT 1
.eqv SYS_EXIT 10

.globl main
main:
    # Beginn der Ausführung anzeigen:
    li $v0, SYS_PUTSTR
    la $a0, str_Start
    syscall

    move $s0, $zero     #int i=0
_print_main:
    li $v0, SYS_PUTSTR
    la $a0, str_Par
    syscall
    
    li $v0, SYS_PUTINT
    move $a0, $s0
    syscall

    li $v0, SYS_PUTSTR
    la $a0, str_ColonTab
    syscall

    addi $s0, $s0, 1
    la $a0, test_perm
    lw $a1, test_perm_length
    jal perm_print

    la $a0, test_perm
    lw $a1, test_perm_length
    jal permnext
    beq $zero, $v0, _end_main
    li $t0, 1000
    blt $s0, $t0, _print_main
    
    li $v0, SYS_PUTSTR
    la $a0, str_Abbruch
    syscall
    
    # Programmende
    li $v0, SYS_EXIT
    syscall

_end_main:
    li $v0, SYS_EXIT
    syscall

# void perm_print(unsigned char *perm, int length)
perm_print:
    move $t0, $zero
    move $t1, $a0
_for:
    add $t2, $t1, $t0
    lbu $t3, 0($t2)

    li $v0, SYS_PUTINT
    move $a0, $t3
    syscall

    li $v0, SYS_PUTSTR
    la $a0, str_Spaces
    syscall

    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    bne $t0, $a1, _for
#_ret:
    li $v0, SYS_PUTSTR
    la $a0, str_Break
    syscall
    jr $ra

# void swap(unsigned char *test_perm, int a, int b)
swap:
    add $t1, $a0, $a1
    add $t2, $a0, $a2
    lbu $t0, 0($t1)
    lbu $t3, 0($t2)
    sb $t3, 0($t1)
    sb $t0, 0($t2)
#_ret:
    jr $ra

    

.data

test_perm_length: .word 4
test_perm: .byte 0, 1, 2, 3

.text

#ENDE VORGABEABSCHNITT

permnext:
    addi $t0, $a0, 0 #Addresse des ersten Elements des Arrays
    addi $t1, $a1, 0 #Lange des Arrays hier
    addi $t2, $t1, -2 #das wird die lauf-Variable i (n-2) sein
    
while1:

    li $t9, 4
    mult $t2, $t9
    mflo $t9
    add $t3, $t9, $t0 #Das ist die Addresse am Index i
    addi $t4, $t3, 4 #Das ist die Addresse des Index i+1
    lw $t3, ($t3) #speichere den Wert and er Addresse des Index i in $t3
    lw $t4, ($t4)
    blt $t2, 0, returnzero #falls i kleiner als 0 ist, wollen wir 0 zurueckgeben
    blt $t3, $t4, endofwhile1 #zeite while Bedingung
    addi $t2, $t2, -1 #dekrementiere i
    j while1

returnzero:

    li $v0, 0
    j end
    
endofwhile1:

    addi $t5, $t1, -1 #laufvariable j (n-1)
    
while2:

    li $t9, 4
    mult $t9, $t5
    mflo $t9
    add $t4, $t9, $t0 #kann $t4 wieder benutzen, da ich es nicht nochmal fuer i+1 brauche
    lw $t4, ($t4)
    bgt $t4, $t3, endofwhile2
    addi $t5, $t5, -1 #dekrementiere j
    j while2
    
endofwhile2:

    addi $a0, $t0, 0
    addi $a1, $t2, 0
    addi $a2, $t5, 0
    addi $t7, $ra, 0 #speichere $ra fuer spaetere zwecke, sonst gehts im naechsten schritt verloren
    jal swap
    addi $t6, $t2, 1
    addi $t5, $t1, -1
    
while3:

    bge $t6, $t5, endofwhile3
    addi $a1, $t6, 0
    addi $a2, $t5, 0
    jal swap
    addi $t6, $t6, 1
    addi $t5, $t5, -1
    j while3
    
endofwhile3:

    li $v0, 1
    j end

end:

    addi $ra, $t7, 0
    jr $ra #return to caller
```

as I said, the program is supposed to show all permutations in lexicographical order but it can't, for reasons stated above

BTW this is the code I wrote in C beforehand which I used to orientate myself while writing my MIPS code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *arr, int i, int j) {
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}

int permnext(int *arr, int n) {
    int i = n - 2;
    while (i >= 0 && arr[i] >= arr[i+1]) {
        i--;
    }
    if (i < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int j = n - 1;
    while (arr[j] <= arr[i]) {
        j--;
    }
    swap(arr, i, j);
    int k = i + 1;
    j = n - 1;
    while (k < j) {
        swap(arr, k, j);
        k++;
        j--;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);

    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } while (permnext(arr, n));

    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE I've considered register conventions, I can't seem to print more than the first permutation though. here's my new code:

```
.data
```

str_Par: .asciiz "("
str_ColonTab: .asciiz "):\t"
str_Start: .asciiz "Das Programm ruft die Funktion permnext auf und zeigt Iterationsnummer und die neu gebildete Permutation an.\n"
str_Abbruch: .asciiz "Ausfuehrung abgebrochen (maximale Iterationsnummer erreicht).\n"
str_Spaces: .asciiz "  "
str_Break: .asciiz "\n"

.text

.eqv SYS_PUTSTR 4       #const define syscall ($v0)
.eqv SYS_RD_INT 5
.eqv SYS_PUTCHAR 11
.eqv SYS_PUTINT 1
.eqv SYS_EXIT 10

.globl main
main:
# Beginn der Ausführung anzeigen:
li $v0, SYS_PUTSTR
la $a0, str_Start
syscall

```
move $s0, $zero     #int i=0
```

_print_main:
li $v0, SYS_PUTSTR
la $a0, str_Par
syscall

```
li $v0, SYS_PUTINT
move $a0, $s0
syscall

li $v0, SYS_PUTSTR
la $a0, str_ColonTab
syscall

addi $s0, $s0, 1
la $a0, test_perm
lw $a1, test_perm_length
jal perm_print

la $a0, test_perm
lw $a1, test_perm_length
jal permnext
beq $zero, $v0, _end_main
li $t0, 1000
blt $s0, $t0, _print_main

li $v0, SYS_PUTSTR
la $a0, str_Abbruch
syscall

# Programmende
li $v0, SYS_EXIT
syscall
```

_end_main:
li $v0, SYS_EXIT
syscall

## void perm_print(unsigned char *perm, int length)

perm_print:
move $t0, $zero
move $t1, $a0
_for:
add $t2, $t1, $t0
lbu $t3, 0($t2)

```
li $v0, SYS_PUTINT
move $a0, $t3
syscall

li $v0, SYS_PUTSTR
la $a0, str_Spaces
syscall

addi $t0, $t0, 1
bne $t0, $a1, _for
```

#_ret:
li $v0, SYS_PUTSTR
la $a0, str_Break
syscall
jr $ra

## void swap(unsigned char *test_perm, int a, int b)

swap:
add $t1, $a0, $a1
add $t2, $a0, $a2
lbu $t0, 0($t1)
lbu $t3, 0($t2)
sb $t3, 0($t1)
sb $t0, 0($t2)
#_ret:
jr $ra

```
#+ BITTE VERVOLLSTAENDIGEN: Persoenliche Angaben zur Hausaufgabe 
#+ -------------------------------------------------------------

# Vorname:
# Nachname:
# Matrikelnummer:

#+ Loesungsabschnitt
#+ -----------------
```

.data

test_perm_length: .word 4
test_perm: .byte 0, 1, 2, 3

.text

permnext:

```
# array address = $s1, length n = $s2, int i = $s3, int j = $s4, return address = $s5, int k = $s6
move $s5, $ra #rueckkehroption zu caller
move $s1, $a0 
move $s2, $a1
add $s3, $s2, -2 #int i = n-2
```

while1:

```
blt $s3, 0, end0

li $t0, 4
mult $t0, $s3
mflo $t0 #offset i 
add $t1, $t0, $s1 #addresse ites Element, alternativ anstatt s3 einfach den offset t0
lw $t2, ($t1) #wert des iten elements

addi $t3, $t1, 4 #addresse i +1
lw $t3, ($t3) #wert des i+1ten elements

blt $t2, $t3, endofwhile1 #falls [i] < [i+1]

    addi $s3, $s3, -1 #$s3 bzw i wird dekrementiert
    j while1
```

end0:

```
li $v0, 0
j end
```

endofwhile1:

```
addi $s4, $s2, -1 # int j ist length n -1
```

while2:

```
li $t0, 4
mult $t0, $s4
mflo $t4
add $t4, $t4, $s1 #addresse des jten elements alternativ $t4 addieren
lw $t4, ($t4) #wert and er stelle j

bgt $t4, $t2, endofwhile2

    addi $s4, $s4, -1 #dekrementiere j
    j while2
```

endofwhile2:

```
move $a0, $s1
move $a1, $s3
move $a2, $s4 #setting parameters for swap

jal swap #swapping i and j

addi $s6, $s3, 1 # k = i +1
addi $s4, $s2, -1 #setze j wieder auf n -1
```

while3:

```
bge $s6, $s4, endofwhile3
    
    move $a0, $s1
    move $a1, $s6
    move $a2, $s4 #setting parameters for swap
    
    jal swap
    
    addi $s6, $s6, 1 #increment k
    addi $s4, $s4, -1 #dekrementiere j
    j while3
```

endofwhile3:

```
li $v0, 1
j end
```

end:

```
move $ra, $s5
jr $ra
```

Answer (score 0):

The CPU registers are effectively global storage, and, each can only hold one value at a time.

So, if one function, say `permnext` uses a register, say `$t0`, and then calls another function, say `swap` that also uses `$t0`, then `swap` "wins", and `$t0` holds the value `swap` put there even as it returns to the caller.

To prevent problems with one function overwriting registers in use by another function, we have what's called the ["calling convention"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention).  It articulates the rules needed to share the registers among any number of functions, say tens of thousands as in a very large real-world program.

That function `swap` is following the conventions, nothing in error to report there.  Its use of `$t0`-`$t3` is legitimate (though it could have done its job using fewer registers, there's nothing wrong with it).  If you look carefully at `swap` in source code or single stepping in the debugger you'll see it repurpose `$t0` with a byte data value, via `lbu $t0, 0($t1)`.  And when `swap` returns to its caller what value will be in `$t0`?  That byte data value, of course, certainly not its prior value!

Function `permnext` fails the calling convention, using temporary registers that it expects to hold values across the call to `swap`.  Putting an important variable, parameter `int *arr` in a temporary register, `$t0`, and letting `swap` wipe it out.  The same holds for return address linkage parameter value in `$ra`..

This register repurposing by `swap` and the expectation that the registers aren't repurposed by `permnext` is plainly visible in debugging — the question is what to do about it, and the answer is to make storage choices consistent with and have expectations consistent with the rules of the calling convention.

Let's also note that `main` is following the calling convention, in using a call-preserved register `$s0` for a variable (its loop control variable, `i`) that it needs to remain valid after calling `permnext` (and also printing).

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75709604/471129

Comment: I thank you for your answer. I've looked into register conventions ( I was supposed to learn this but I skipped that one hearing) and I've come up with another code but it just prints the first permutation 0123. I derived it from c code I wrote which works perfectly fine. I think I'll do a new question as I don't know how to add that content into this question, if you want to exhaust yourself with my code. very thankful for the answer so far. EDIT actually I can just edit my question so ill update it here

Comment: Thankfully MIPS makes calling conventions easy to remember with its register naming. You're supposed to preserve registers that begin with `s` and can discard the ones that begin with `t`. 'T' is for trash, 's' is for save. That's how I remember it.